# Classes for view file?

Tags: php

I am not sure how to explain in detail but I will try my best.

Currenly I have a php file it look something like this:

```
   $SQL_Cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE restaurant_id = '$restaurantID'");
    while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($SQL_Cat))
    {
        $CategoryID = $category['id'];
        echo $category['name'];

        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = '" . $CategoryID . "'");
        while($item = mysql_fetch_array($q))
        {          
            $item_name = $item['name'];
            echo $item_name;                
             }
        }
```

As you can see there are $category and $item ,how to create this
class (classname/{Category, Item}) to use the view.  Example below:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <table  border=0 Cellspacing='0'>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $category->name; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach ($category->items as $item): ?>       
        <tr>
            <td>
              <?php echo $item->name; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So I can keep SQL queries away from a view file.

Comment: is this a framework your using?

Comment: Do you need a way to tie your view to your class or have you already done that and just need to know how to pass data from one to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$SQL_Cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE restaurant_id = '$restaurantID'");
while ($category = mysql_fetch_object($SQL_Cat))
{
    $category->items = array();
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE category_id = '" . $category->id . "'");
    while($item = mysql_fetch_object($q))
    {          
        $category->items[] = $item;
    }

    $categories[] = $category;
}
```

Comment: But you REALLY should review your logic - queries in cycle is a BAD idea.

Comment: Really? So how would you do it from my example?

Comment: @user622378 Use `JOIN` statement for e.g. or `WHERE category_id IN` as second query.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PDO and fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) it into an object. PDO is capable of automatically constructing objects so you don't have to write class definitions.